# Can Google Cloud Platform administration be separated from Google Workspace?

Tags: permissions, gcp, administrative-privileges

Is it possible to separate GCP Administration from Google Workspace Administration? Or by being super admin of an Organization in Workspace you inherit super admin permissions in the organization for GCP and vice versa? I would be interested in making the administration of the two platforms totally invisible and independent between the admin accounts of each part. Thanks.